# htmlTable adding spaces to row labels

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using htmlTable with RMarkdown to generate a report and I'm noticing that the function is adding non-blank spaces around my row labels. The problem is that when the label wraps to a second line, it makes the first line look indented when it shouldn't be.

I've double checked that my labels don't include any extraneous spaces, so it's not that. I stepped through the table generation and it seems that it occurs right as I run htmlTable.

Any suggestions on how to get this to stop happening / workaround? I'm worried I'm going to have to wrap all of my row labels in divs in order to adjust for this....

[Issue Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4kgY.png)

...and the corresponding HTML:

```
<td style="text-align: left;">
&nbsp;My ideas are seriously considered in my unit&nbsp;
</td>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The `&nbsp;` tags create spaces in your HTML.
Have you tried removing them?